# How to pass parameter to fsck at boot time

Tags: arch-linux, boot, fsck

I want to make `fsck` to run by default with `-y` at boot time to try to force automatic repair. Any idea how this can be done under Arch Linux?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fsck#Forcing_the_check

Comment: @jasonwryan tnx. I actually need `fsck.repair`.

Comment: why the down vote! care to explain?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort"...

Comment: @jasonwryan well I think this is a very basic question. there is not much in terms of "research" that can be included in the question without making the question unnecessarily lengthly.

Comment: If you had bothered to read the wiki, or the man page, there would have been no need to ask a question. That is what "no research" means.

Comment: @jasonwryan I actually did search and did read the exact same page you mentioned but there was no notion of `repair`, it just talks about force `fsck`.  And I did read the man page for `fsck` where I got the idea of `-y`. But I did not read `systemd-fsck` because I did not know such a thing exists. I just think giving more constructive feedback works better.

Answer (score 6):

I just found it myself. Need to pass [kernel command line parameter](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html) `fsck.repair=yes`. In case of Raspberry Pi this needs to be appended to `/boot/cmdline.txt` file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the right direction! It would be worth noting in your answer that `/boot/cmdline.txt` appears to be specific to raspbian, and that other ways to pass parameters to the kernel can be found here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters

Comment: tnx @Johann. it is noted. btw `/boot/cmdline.txt` is specific to Raspberry Pi not raspbian. I am using armARCH with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Oh, right...raspbian is Debian based :)